# Core Content types not available

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a weird issue troubling my Drupal site. Upon clicking 'Add Content', my Drupal website automatically redirects to a couple of custom content types that I created using the 'Add content type' feature. For some reason, all the existing core content types such as 'Basic page', 'Article', 'Book' have disappeared.

Further probing, when I click the 'Content types' link in 'Structure>Content types', all of these content types exist and are listed, however for some reason I am unable to use them.

I am not sure where I have goofed up here, so I want to ask you guys and check what's wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you get directly to `node/add/page`, `node/add/article` etc?

Comment: Yes, they traverse to the correct content types but are not displayed alongside the custom content types on the 'Add content' page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**
I have experienced this same problem... in fact on a current project I lost a complete day of work (I wasn't backing up my DB often enough & my fix was to restore my DB) in attempt to resolve it.
Once I found Radix's answer I realized that was definitely what I had just done (disable all of those items in the navigation menu).

**Procedure/Fix:**
I then took it one step further, since, in my estimation putting these links in the navigation menu must have been an error (what business do they have there??).
I went to Structure->Menus and clicked the "list links" errr link.
Next I clicked the "edit" link on the Add content sub-menu item.
In the Edit window I selected the ----Content sub-menu of the Configuration menu.

I then verified that clicking Add content from the management menu AND from the Content window brought me to the links I was expecting, and it did.

**Drawback:**
 I found that when adding new content types you have to modify their automated menu link by finding them under the navigation menu & setting their parent menu as ------ Add content

**Summary:**
 Moved the Add content menu to a more logical location (so I could use the navigation menu for my own purposes without losing the ability to add content), however this requires an extra step when creating custom content types.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been asked in several formats, but as it keeps rearing its head, I will respond with a detailed explanation.

When attempting to "Add content" under administration-->Content, it is quite common to find that the content type menu items become disabled (don't know why). This can easily be remedied by re-enabling the content types in the navigation menu, like this:

Go to administration-->structure-->menus-->navigation and you will see all (or some) of your content types are disabled in the menu. Just re-enable them and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

This may also be due to problem with the database:
If two or more entries in the node_type table have the same orig_type value, some of them may not be displayed. Compare this report: [Drupal: Content type in database not in the list of content types in Structure>Content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314691/drupal-content-type-in-database-not-in-the-list-of-content-types-in-structurec)