# No base content types (Basic Page & Story) in a new Drupal 7.22 installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a blank 7.22 installation that I'm ready to add content to, but the default content types are unavailable. I can get Blog entry & Book page to appear by enabling the appropriate modules.

I read this post: [Core Content types not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921810/core-content-types-not-available)
but I do not see Menus within the Structure admin menu.

Should I have Menus as an option or is that a difference between versions? I am new to Drupal so I'm not sure if my installation is messed up or I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Visit admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation, and enable those disabled menus.

Comment: Thanks but I get "The requested page "/admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation" could not be found." I do have clean URLs enabled. I think I'm going to wipe this installation out and try again.

Comment: you'd better. And check [Drupal's system requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) first, as it looks like something went really wrong with your installation